# How to toggle syntax with a single key

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

To turn on syntax we normally use: `:syntax on` and to turn it off we do: `:syntax off`. I would like to define a single key, maybe using `<expr>` to toggle syntax. My problem is how to get the current syntax state, so I can use it in a ternary operator.

Something like this:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>s SyntaxState() ? ":syntax off" : ":syntax on"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually want `syntax enable` (for good reasons which I’ll leave to the `:help` to explain).

I created this custom command to toggle syntax; you could adjust the mapping similarly:

```
command SynToggle
      \ if exists("g:syntax_on") |
      \   syntax off |
      \ else |
      \   syntax enable |
      \ endif
```

This leaves you with

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>s exists('g:syntax_on') ? ':syntax off<CR>' : ':syntax enable<CR>'
```

Comment: Thanks! My actual command turned out to be: `:nnoremap <expr> <Leader>s exists('g:syntax_on') ? ':syntax off<cr>' : ':syntax enable<cr>'` . The idea is to leave more free keys to use in other situations.

Comment: @SergioAraujo of course; keys was just a placeholder

Comment: The big thing here is `exists('g:syntax_on')` all the rest depends on how we know vimscript, its logic etc. But anyway, our vimrc is becoming smarter, I think. Our community is growing because we have people willing to help, always!