# switch toggle function - background

Tags: key-bindings, functions

I'm trying to assign a key toggle to switch between dark or light background. I wrote this function:

```
function ToggleBG()
    let l:bg='set background?'
    if l:bg==dark
        :set background=light
    elseif l:bg==light
        :set background=dark
    endif    
endfunction

nmap <F6> :call ToggleBG()<cr>
```

It doesn't work, error,

```
E121: Undefined variable: dark  
E15: Invalid expression: l:bg==dark
```

The logic is, retrieve current bg setting `set background?`, put it in a local variable, l:bg; if it's dark switch it to light and vice versa.
Assign the function to <kbd>F6</kbd> key.

Using Vim 8.1 and Neovim. Any ideas how will this work?

Comment: `let l:bg = 'set background?'` just assigns the string. I would take a look at `:help :let-&` and `:help eval` in general

Comment: Further inspiration: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24417/10604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute several times in a command line:

```
:let &bg=(&bg=='light'?'dark':'light')
```

It will change background from light to dark to light...

Then map it to F6:

```
nnoremap <F6> :let &bg=(&bg=='light'?'dark':'light')<cr>
```

Check

- `:help :let-&` -- on how to access option values in vimscript.
- `:help trinary` -- for `expr ? expr : expr` description

Comment: It was that simple! Thank you!